# Use jq to find array element by containing string

Tags: json, jq

I have an array "operations" from which I would like to return all the elements that contain a  matching string like `"w51"`. Until now, all the samples I have found dealt with key value pairs. I am using `jq '.operations[]' < file` to retrieve the elements.

```
{
  "operations": [
    [
      "create",
      "w51",
      "rwt.widgets.Label",
      {
        "parent": "w41",
        "style": [
          "NONE"
        ],
        "bounds": [
          101,
          0,
          49,
          42
        ],
        "tabIndex": -1,
        "customVariant": "variant_pufferLabelLogout"
      }
    ],
    [
      "create",
      "w39",
      "rwt.widgets.Composite",
      {
        "parent": "w34",
        "style": [
          "NONE"
        ],
        "children": [
          "w52"
        ],
        "bounds": [
          0,
          42,
          762,
          868
        ],
        "tabIndex": -1,
        "clientArea": [
          0,
          0,
          762,
          868
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

My expected output when searching for an array element that contains "w51" would be this:

```
[
      "create",
      "w51",
      "rwt.widgets.Label",
      {
        "parent": "w41",
        "style": [
          "NONE"
        ],
        "bounds": [
          101,
          0,
          49,
          42
        ],
        "tabIndex": -1,
        "customVariant": "variant_pufferLabelLogout"
      }
]
```

Comment: Did you try `jq '.operations[] | select(IN(.[];"w51"))' file`?

Comment: This gives me an error: `jq: error: IN/1 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:`

Comment: update to version 1.6

Comment: Unfortunately I do t have influence on the system I’m working on. Is there no other way?

Comment: there is. you can define IN/1 and IN/2 in before your filter like this: `jq 'def IN(s): reduce (first(select(. == s)) | true) as $v (false; if . or $v then true else false end); def IN(src; s): reduce (src|IN(s)) as $v (false; if . or $v then true else false end); .operations[] | select(IN(.[];"w51"))' file`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works. I'm on a raspberry pi and there doesn't seem to be a v1.6 release for arm processors yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use jq version 1.4 or later, the following should produce the desired output:

```
.operations[]
| select( index("w51") )
```

### Alternatives

There are many alternatives, depending on which version of jq you have.  If your jq has `any/0`, the following is an efficient option:

```
.operations[] | select( any(. == "w51" ) )
```